# Must a woman cover her hair during childbirth?

Tags: halacha, women, medicine, pregnancy-birth, hair-covering

Does a woman need to cover her hair during childbirth or other major medical procedures?

Comment: Why would you believe otherwise?

Comment: @GershonGold 1) lo nit'na torah l'malachei hashares 2)choleh sh'yeish bo sakana 3) kavod ha'brios (are we really going to ask her to hold onto her tichel while pushing out a baby?) 4)this is not a situation that is conducive to hirhur aveirah (similar to sotah)

Comment: Since it was not Nitna to angels, therefore she should keep her hair covered. What does Sakana have to do with uncovering her hair? What is the Sakana of keeping it covered? Why does she need to hold it? If it is fitting properly it remains on?

Comment: @GershonGold #1 is a general principle that the torah does not ask people to be angelic, meaning to go to superhuman lengths. similar to "Hashem does not overly trouble his creations". #2 if her life is in danger she should be exempt from extraneous actions and focus on the task at hand #3 I don't even know how to respond to that except to say it ain't always so pashut -- but in any case if it does fall off would she have to put it back on? Can I assume you concur with point #4?

Comment: -1 I don't think you've satisfactorily justified why the obligation might disappear in this case; hirhur is not per se the primary reason why a woman would have to cover her hair. On a case by case basis, if it is logistically difficult for the woman to cover her hair, I would not expect objections to her inability to cover her hair. But why a blanket dispensation?

Comment: I'll add one additional reason: During childbirth, she is exposing her actual erva.  Saying, "I must cover my hair for modesty while you focus on my gynecological bits" seems patently ridiculous.  That said, the story is told of a woman who, on meeting her new gynecologist, refused to shake his hand because of negia.  Ridiculous as it is, it might be the halacha.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen She isn't exposing her Erva to anyone aside from the doctor (not even her husband!). Your logic implies that a women giving birth can do so in the nude in Times Square.

Comment: @DoubleAA, there may be any number of hospital staff present as she delivers.  But more to the point, whoever is in the room sees her ervah.  Seeing her hair seems a small matter by comparison.  Should she wear thigh high stockings, since her legs are an ervah too?

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen You know I meant "aside from the doctor [and other relevant staff]". Should she be topless as well since her legs are showing? You aren't making a salient point. It's clear that she should maintain a level of modesty that is reasonable given the circumstances and your "additional reason" has done absolutely nothing to disprove that.

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave It would be great if you could edit your question to include the justifications you mentioned, rather than leaving them in comments, where they are likely to get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

not likely. would be similar to asking would a women need to cover her hair when showering. when one is in the midst of something which requires to be disrobed then at that moment we aren't concerned with her not being covered. if someone was normally covered in blood they wouldn't pray nor say G-d's name yet when the cohanim were in the middle of offering the avodah we weren't concerned with them being dirty while they were in the middle of it. context is an important factor when making decisions. a funny when to put it... knowing that tomato is a fruit is knowing a fact but wisdom is knowing that you don't get a smoothie if you put it in the blender

Comment: Why is childbirth something that requires her hair to be uncovered? Or if one place needs to be uncovered than any can? So she can give birth completely naked in Times Square if she wants?